# Azure search document results is not binding to model

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

trying to use azure search documents and bind to a specific model

Model

```
    /// <summary>
    /// AzureSearchReturnModel
    /// </summary>
    public class AzureSearchReturnModel
    {
        /*// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the module identifier.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The module identifier.
        /// </value>
        public int ModuleId { get; set; }*/

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the end item identifier.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The end item identifier.
        /// </value>
        [SimpleField(IsFilterable = true)]
        public int EndItemId { get; set; }

        /*// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the end item type identifier.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The end item type identifier.
        /// </value>
        public int EndItemTypeId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the name of the file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The name of the file.
        /// </value>
        public string FileName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the file extension.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The file extension.
        /// </value>
        public string FileExtension { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the name of the module type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The name of the module type.
        /// </value>
        public string ModuleTypeName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the size of the file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The size of the file.
        /// </value>
        public long FileSize { get; set; }*/
    }
```

Here is a picture of my azure search settings on portal.azure for my index:

[image]

Here is the code I'm calling to obtain the results:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the files azure BLOB results from azure search.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="moduleId">The module identifier.</param>
        /// <param name="endItemId">The end item identifier.</param>
        /// <param name="endItemTypeId">The end item type identifier.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public IEnumerable<FileManagerFileSystemItem> GetFilesAzureBlobResultsFromAzureSearch(int moduleId, int endItemId, int endItemTypeId)
        {

            SearchOptions options = new SearchOptions()
            {
                Filter = string.Format("endItemId eq '82'", endItemId),
                /*Filter = string.Format("moduleId eq {0} and endItemId eq {1} and endItemTypeId eq {2}", moduleId.ToString(), endItemId.ToString(), endItemTypeId.ToString()),*/
            };
            SearchResults<AzureSearchReturnModel> results;
            SearchClient searchClient = AzureKeyVaultUtilities.CreateSearchClientForQueries();

            options.Select.Add("endItemId");

            /*options.Select.Add("moduleId");
            options.Select.Add("endItemId");
            options.Select.Add("endItemTypeId");
            options.Select.Add("moduleType");
            options.Select.Add("fileName");
            options.Select.Add("fileExtension");
            options.Select.Add("metadata_storage_size");*/

            results = searchClient.Search<AzureSearchReturnModel>("*", options);

            return Enumerable.Empty<FileManagerFileSystemItem>();
        }
```

The code runs without any issues, but my data is not binding to my model.

What am I doing wrong?

It appears the count is right? When I run the query via portal.azure.us it shows me 4 results:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the info you provided, I created an index and write a demo for you.This is my index:
[image]

And my code below:

First I upload some docs and then query them with binding to a specific model as you want :

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Search;
using Microsoft.Azure.Search.Models;

namespace AzureSearchTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var searchServiceName = "";
            var cred = "";
            var indexName = "";

            SearchServiceClient serviceClient = new SearchServiceClient(searchServiceName, new SearchCredentials(cred));
            ISearchIndexClient indexClient = serviceClient.Indexes.GetClient(indexName);
            
            //UploadDocuments(indexClient);
            var results = indexClient.Documents.Search<AzureSearchReturnModel>("*");

            Console.WriteLine(results.Results.Count);

        }

        private static void UploadDocuments(ISearchIndexClient indexClient) {
            var AzureSearchReturnModels = new AzureSearchReturnModel[] {
                new AzureSearchReturnModel(){
                    ModuleId = "1" ,
                    EndItemId = "100",
                    EndItemTypeId = "200",
                    FileName= "test file 1",
                    FileExtension ="txt",
                    ModuleTypeName = "demo",
                    FileSize = 20000
                },
                 new AzureSearchReturnModel(){
                    ModuleId = "2" ,
                    EndItemId = "100",
                    EndItemTypeId = "200",
                    FileName= "test file 2",
                    FileExtension ="aaa",
                    ModuleTypeName = "demo",
                    FileSize = 50000
                },
                  new AzureSearchReturnModel(){
                    ModuleId = "3" ,
                    EndItemId = "100",
                    EndItemTypeId = "200",
                    FileName= "test file 3",
                    FileExtension ="bbb",
                    ModuleTypeName = "demo",
                    FileSize = 60000
                }

            };

            var batch = IndexBatch.Upload(AzureSearchReturnModels);
            indexClient.Documents.Index(batch);


        }
    }

    public class AzureSearchReturnModel
    {
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "moduleId")]
        public String ModuleId { get; set; }


        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "endItemId")]
        public String EndItemId { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "endItemTypeId")]
        public String EndItemTypeId { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "fileName")]
        public string FileName { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "fileExtension")]
        public string FileExtension { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "moduleType")]
        public string ModuleTypeName { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "metadata_storage_size")]
        public long FileSize { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Appears I'm missing the `[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "endItemId")]` I'll try this in the morning.